# Netbeans CSS auto format

Tags: css, netbeans, autoformatting

In Netbeans 6.9.1 (PHP bundle) the code format (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) doesn't seem to work on CSS files, that is when I try to run it nothing happens. Is it normal or am I missing something?

Comment: Does the PHP bundle say it features HTML/CSS formatting?

Comment: I just tried it and it does indeed format CSS, at least for indentation - something must be different with your setup.

Comment: try to select all n ALT+SHIFT+F or

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've check it in my version of Neatbeans (Also 6.9.1) and it seems to work fine.

If it's not working for you, perhaps you need to check your Keymap settings.

To do so,

1. click Tools
2. Choose Options
3. Select the Keymap tab
4. Perform the Alt+Shift+F keymap in the "Search in shortcuts" input field
5. Make sure you get the following:

   ```
   Actions = Format

   Shortcut = Alt+Shift+F

   Category = Source
   ```

Also check that your tabs and indents are setup in the Formatting tab under the Editor Section of the Options panel.

Hope that helps,
Tom

Comment: I followed your solution and found nothing like you mentioned in #5. What I supposed to do to fix it?

Comment: He actually does not answer the question : Netbeans does not support CSS formatting nor is there any plugin for this purpose yet.

Answer (score 1):

(tested with Netbeans 12.0)
You can use regular expressions to add newlines:

1. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> or click Menu Edit -> Replace...
2. Find What: "([{};])" (without quotes)
3. activate regular expressions (button with caption **.*** or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)
4. Replace With: "$1\n" (without quotes)
5. Replace All

Then you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to auto-indent