# Automatically indentation with netbeans

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery-ui in my project and its css.

Is there a way to automatically indent and expand the css code in Netbeans? As you probably know it's not very readable and i'd like to make it clearer.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640592/netbeans-css-auto-format and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7356785/formatting-in-netbeans-css-specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently css formatting is not available in Netbeans. I use this online tool to format css http://styleneat.com/ it give very good formatting.